# Typescript code compiles although type should be flagged

Tags: typescript

I have this code to model a result type. The Failure type would contain all possible failures. 'Incorrect' is not one of them, but I nevertheless can return Incorrect as a Failure.

```
type Try<T, E> = Success<T> | Failures<E> | E;

// User code

type Failure = FileNotFound | NameNotFound;

class FileNotFound extends BaseFailure {}
class NameNotFound extends BaseFailure {}

class Incorrect extends BaseFailure {}

type Result<T> = Try<T, Failure>

function y() {
  let x1 = x(1);
  if (x1.isSuccess) {
  } else {
    x1.hasMany;
  }
}

function x(a:number): Result<String> {
  if (a>3) {
    return new Success("Hallo");
  } else {
    return new Incorrect();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide all the types in the code ? Some are not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility. So when it decides whether the class  `Incorrect` is compatible with `Failure` is compares the structure of `Incorrect` with the members of the `Failure` union. Doing this it will find that `FileNotFound` has the same structure as `Incorrect` and are thus compatible.

To get around this you can add a member (preferably `private`) to all classes in the union. This for example will fail:

```
class Success<T> { constructor(public value: T) { } isSuccess: true = true }
type Try<T, E> = Success<T> | E;

class BaseFailure {
    isSuccess: false
}

type Failure = FileNotFound | NameNotFound;

class FileNotFound extends BaseFailure { private _type: "filenotfound" }
class NameNotFound extends BaseFailure { private _type: "namenotfound" }

class Incorrect extends BaseFailure { }

type Result<T> = Try<T, Failure>

function y() {
    let x1 = x(1);
    if (x1.isSuccess) {
    } else {
    }
}

function x(a: number): Result<String> {
    if (a > 3) {
        return new Success("Hallo");
    } else {
        return new Incorrect(); // error now
    }
}
```

You can also include the private field in `BaseFailure` to force implementers to specify it:

```
class BaseFailure<T> {
    isSuccess: false
    private __type: T
}


class FileNotFound extends BaseFailure<"filenotfound"> { }
class NameNotFound extends BaseFailure<"namenotfound"> { }

class Incorrect extends BaseFailure<"incorrect"> { }
```

Allowing some nominal typing has long been discussed (see [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202)) but for now this is the best we can do

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.